Concatenating the feature vector to the sentence embedding causes the model to predict all samples into the same class
This is my current code for concatenating the feature vector to the embedding:
def get_dataset(absa_dim, tokenizer, bert_model, set_name, device='cuda'):
    df = pd.read_csv(f"{set_name}.csv")   
    df = df[['sentences_1', f'absa_{absa_method}_1', 'sentences_2', f'absa_{absa_method}_2', aspect]]
           
    sent_1 = df['sentences_1'].astype(str).to_list()
    sent_2 = df['sentences_2'].astype(str).to_list()
    absa_1 = df[f'absa_1'].astype(float).to_list()
    absa_2 = df[f'absa_2'].astype(float).to_list()
   
    labels = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.long)
   

    # --------- Embedding here ---------

    batch_size = 1024
    embeddings = []
    
    dense_absa_layer = nn.Linear(1, absa_dim).to(device)
    
    dense_layer = nn.Linear(768 + absa_dim, 768).to(device)
    
    def minmax_scale_item(tensor, min_val=-0.9, max_val=0.9):
        tensor_min = tensor.min(dim=1, keepdim=True)[0]  # Minimum values for each item
        tensor_max = tensor.max(dim=1, keepdim=True)[0]  # Maximum values for each item

        scaled_tensor = (tensor - tensor_min) / (tensor_max - tensor_min + 1e-7)  # Avoid division by zero
        scaled_tensor = scaled_tensor * (max_val - min_val) + min_val

        return scaled_tensor
    
    def get_doc_sep_embed():
        bert_model.eval()
        inputs = tokenizer(
                "[DOC_SEP]",
                return_tensors="pt",
                padding=True,
                truncation=True,
                max_length=5  # Adjust max length as necessary
            ).to(device)
        outputs = bert_model(**inputs)
        embeddings = outputs.pooler_output.float()
        return embeddings
        
    doc_sep_token_embedding = get_doc_sep_embed()
    
    def get_combined_embeddings(embedding_1, embedding_2, tokenizer, device='cuda'):
        doc_sep_embedding = doc_sep_token_embedding.unsqueeze(0).expand(embedding_1.shape[0], -1, -1)  # Shape: (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim)
        combined_embeddings = torch.cat([embedding_1, doc_sep_embedding, embedding_2], dim=1)

        if combined_embeddings.shape[1] > 512:
            combined_embeddings = combined_embeddings[:, :512]
        else:
            padding = torch.zeros((combined_embeddings.shape[0], 512 - combined_embeddings.shape[1], combined_embeddings.shape[2]), device=device)
            combined_embeddings = torch.cat([combined_embeddings, padding], dim=1)

        return combined_embeddings
    
    # Precompute ABSA vectors
    batch_absa_1 = torch.tensor(absa_1, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(-1).to(device)
    batch_absa_2 = torch.tensor(absa_2, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(-1).to(device)
    
    # Dense layer to adjust ABSA embeddings dimension
    dense_absa_layer = nn.Linear(1, absa_dim).to(device)

    if absa_dims > 0:
        with torch.no_grad():
            dense_absa_layer.eval()
            absa_vec_1 = dense_absa_layer(batch_absa_1)  # (num_samples, absa_dim)
            absa_vec_2 = dense_absa_layer(batch_absa_2)  # (num_samples, absa_dim)

            absa_vec_1 = minmax_scale_item(absa_vec_1)  # (num_samples, absa_dim)
            absa_vec_2 = minmax_scale_item(absa_vec_2)  # (num_samples, absa_dim)
    
    for i in tqdm(range(0, len(sent_1), batch_size)):
        batch_sent_1 = sent_1[i:i+batch_size]
        batch_sent_2 = sent_2[i:i+batch_size]

        with torch.no_grad():
            bert_model.eval()
            dense_layer.eval()
            
            # Embed sentences 1 (using pooled output)
            
            inputs_1 = tokenizer(
                batch_sent_1,
                return_tensors="pt",
                padding=True,
                truncation=True,
                max_length=255  # Adjust max length as necessary
            ).to(device)
            outputs_1 = bert_model(**inputs_1)
            sentence_embeddings_1 = outputs_1.pooler_output.float()

            # Embed sentences 2 (using pooled output)
            inputs_2 = tokenizer(
                batch_sent_2,
                return_tensors="pt",
                padding=True,
                truncation=True,
                max_length=256  # Adjust max length as necessary
            ).to(device)
            outputs_2 = bert_model(**inputs_2)
            sentence_embeddings_2 = outputs_2.pooler_output.float()
            
            if absa_dim > 0:
                
                # Concatenate embedding with precomputed ABSA vector
                concat_1 = torch.cat([sentence_embeddings_1, absa_vec_1[i:i + batch_size]], dim=-1)
                concat_2 = torch.cat([sentence_embeddings_2, absa_vec_2[i:i + batch_size]], dim=-1)

                # Pass through dense layer (output 768)
                concat_1 = dense_layer(concat_1)
                concat_2 = dense_layer(concat_2)
                
                # Combine embeddings with [DOC_SEP] token
                combined_embeddings = get_combined_embeddings(concat_1.unsqueeze(1), concat_2.unsqueeze(1), tokenizer, device)
                
            else:
                combined_embeddings = get_combined_embeddings(sentence_embeddings_1.unsqueeze(1), sentence_embeddings_2.unsqueeze(1), tokenizer, device)
        
            # Append to embeddings list
            embeddings.append(combined_embeddings.cpu())

        del inputs_1, inputs_2, outputs_1, outputs_2
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        
    X = torch.cat(embeddings, dim=0).to('cpu')
    
    y = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.long)
    
    return X, y


Basically, here's what I'm doing:

I embed sentence 1 into a tensor.
I embed sentence 2 into a tensor.
I transform the ABSA score of sentence 1 into a tensor of size absa_dim.
I transform the ABSA score of sentence 2 into a tensor of size absa_dim.
I concatenate the sentence embeddings and the ABSA embeddings, resulting in a new size of
768 + absa_dim for both sentence 1 and sentence 2.
I then use a dense layer to reduce the concatenated vectors back to a dimension of 768.
Finally, I merge sentence 1 and sentence 2 with a special token [DOC_SEP] in the middle.

I perform these steps for both the training and test sets. However, I encounter a problem where all predicted samples fall into the same class. This issue does not occur when I do not concatenate the ABSA vector to the embedding.
What could I be doing wrong, and how can I fix this?
I have changed the model, using a custom CNN and fine-tuning BERT, and the model doesn't seem to be the problem. I think the issue lies in the embedding process.
